# LAYOUT PERSONALIZADO IDENTITY ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Tengo en mi aplicacion asp.net core mvc una vista personalizada para el login, pero estoy teniendo dificultades para hacer que esta al ejecutar la aplicacion sea la que se muestre. Estoy utilizando la vista para el login de Identity Core, la utilizo o comparto con mi vista LayoutLogin que tengo personalizada.

Resulta que en el viewStart si yo coloco la ruta de mi vista personalizada que comparte el diseño de la vista login que genera Identity Core. Me muestra esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no la muestra completa como tal, si yo ponga la ruta en la URL lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me muestra la vista que es, no entiendo porque al colocar la URL si la muestra y al ejecutar la App no.

Alguien que me diga que podria ser por favor!

Comment: ¿Has intentado cambiar la referencia del `@Layout` ? Por otro lado, revisa https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 para aumentar las chances de obtener respuestas. Saludos.